# Tax Calculation for discounted items

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, discount

Having a huge problem with sales tax calculation.
Magento 1.9

In NY state clothing and shoes under $110 cannot be charged with tax, and items in magento store that were more than $110 and after discount price went bellow $110 are still being taxed.

[image: Tax settings]

[image: checkout page]

Here is how I have it set up
and this is how it comes up on checkout.
original price on this jacket is $223 and after 60% sale its $89 however magento still adds tax to the discounted price. 
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: As far as I am aware Magento, out of the box, does not have the ability to set a threshold like $110 for taxation. If you have this configured somewhere it sounds like you might have some additional extension installed that provides this.

Comment: I don't have any extensions set up, I only have 2 tax rules set up. 

Regular Tax rate - Retail Customer-Taxable Goods Shoes and Cloths  US-NY-RATE-8.875        
Products under 110 tax rate - Retail Customer-Taxable Goods Genral  US-NY-RATE-under110

Answer (score 1):

Under `System > Configuration > Tax > Calculation Settings` there are options for the order tax rules are applied, including `Apply Customer Tax` which can be either `Before Discount` or `After Discount`, I'm assuming you currently have it set to `Before Discount`.

Comment: I have it set to After Discount